# How do I change the style of a floatingactionbutton?

Tags: codenameone

How do I change the transparency of the text on a Sub floating action button?
Ive tried making a uiid and deriving the floatingactionbutton, which didnt work.  And I also made one to derive the floatingactiontext, which also didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize the color in two places both in the round border and in the background color while making transparency 0.

See the following screenshots:
[image]

[image]